# Default sort order in FHIR list query

Tags: hl7-fhir, hapi-fhir

There is a parameter available called _sort to specify the field but I would like to understand what is the default sorting parameter when we retrieve list from any of the resources in HL7 FHIR.

I have compared the ID and read the documentation. There is no luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

FHIR does not dictate how a server should sort, so it will depend on the server implementation.

Servers are supposed to indicate their sorting in the self link (see http://hl7.org/fhir/search.html#conformance), and to honor the _sort parameter when that is on the request.

Comment: Thank you. Is there any way to check indices in FHIR?

Comment: Resources do not have an index associated with them. You should view them as a collection of objects, which you can sort on certain parameters.